# How to configure Doctrine to use yaml mapping on Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping, yaml, symfony4

I'm new to Symfony **4**

I use Doctrine an I want to use **yaml** entity mapping.
So i configured the file `doctrine.yaml` and change `type:annotation` to `type:yml`.

And when I tried `php bin/console make:entity`, there is no yaml mapping file generated linked to this entity

this is my `doctrine.yaml` file:

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4

        # With Symfony 3.3, remove the `resolve:` prefix
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: yml
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Comment: YAML is going to be removed from Doctrine, see https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/776

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An example of mapping following your needs:

Change the file name including the "**orm**" text `doctrine.orm.yaml`, and take a look at the `dir` option in the example below (*that follows your needs*):

```
App:
    is_bundle: false
    type: yml
    # "dir" in this case must be pointed where are stored your doctrine files (can be anywhere inside the project dir)
    dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/config/doctrine"
    prefix: App\Entity
```

Reference: [Doctrine yaml mapping (v2.6 current)](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/yaml-mapping.html)

Comment: @redigaffi link updated for the current version and thanks for notifying me.

Comment: I have the same problem in symfony 5.1 with annotations and unfortunately I can't find a solution with your solution....

Comment: @Alex open a question on SO BUT remember that yaml driver was deprecated and removed from version 3.0 so it is strongly recommended to use another mapping driver like xml

Comment: yes, I made my question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63367323/symfony-5-1-bundle-migration-result-in-no-mapping-information-to-process 
yaml is deprecated? all my symfony 5.1 web skeleton came configured with yaml by default! Should I change it?

Comment: @Alex yes is deprecated as mapping driver in Doctrine (read the reference link in my answer).